# razor conditional attributes to output html

Tags: razor

I'm using some conditional logic in razor to show/hide attributes...

Can this be written in one line?

```
<div
    @if (!isEditOrCopyMode && !Model.IsRangeDefaultsSet)
    {
        @:id="hidden-frame-thickness" style="display: none"
    }
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div @if(!isEditOrCopyMode && !Model.IsRangeDefaultsSet){<text>id="hidden-frame-thickness" style="display: none"</text>} >
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use inline if-statements, like this:

```
<div id="@(!isEditOrCopyMode && !Model.IsRangeDefaultsSet ? "hidden-frame-thickness" : null)" style="@(!isEditOrCopyMode && !Model.IsRangeDefaultsSet ? "display: none;" : null)">
```

Or, since you have two conditions, merge them first:

```
<div id="@(isNotEditOrCopyModeOrRangeDefaultsSet ? "hidden-frame-thickness" : null)" style="@(!isNotEditOrCopyModeOrRangeDefaultsSet ? "display: none;" : null)">
```